# How to rearrange row of data frame using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, conda

I have a data frame where data is located in another column and I want to take those dates from that column and create a date column and store them. Here is my sample data.

```
df=[['Monday, 13 January 2020','',''],['Task 1',13588,'Jack'],['','','Address 1'],['','','City 1'],['Task 2',13589,'Ammie'],['','','Address 2'],['','','City'],['Task 3',13589,'Amanda'],['','','Address 3'],['','','City 3'],['Tuesday, 14 January 2020','',''],['Task 4',13587,'Chelsea'],['','','Address 4'],['','','City 4'],['Task 5','13586','Ibrahim'],['','','Address 5'],['','','City 5'],['Task 6',13585,'Kate'],['','','Address 6'],['','','City 6']]

df=pd.DataFrame(df)
df.columns = ['Task','ID','Supervisor']
df=df.replace(np.nan,'')
df

    Task    ID  Supervisor
0   Monday, 13 January 2020     
1   Task 1  13588   Jack
2           Address 1
3           City 1
4   Task 2  13589   Ammie
5           Address 2
6           City
7   Task 3  13589   Amanda
8           Address 3
9           City 3
10  Tuesday, 14 January 2020        
11  Task 4  13587   Chelsea
12          Address 4
13          City 4
14  Task 5  13586   Ibrahim
15          Address 5
16          City 5
17  Task 6  13585   Kate
18          Address 6
19          City 6
```

And I want to get the following output.

```
    Date                    Task    ID      Supervisor
0 Monday, 13 January 2020   Task 1  13588   Jack Address 1 City 1
1 Monday, 13 January 2020   Task 2  13589   Ammie Address 2 City
2 Monday, 13 January 2020   Task 3  13589   Amanda Address 3 City 3
3 Tuesday, 14 January 2020  Task 4  13587   Chelsea Address 4 City 4
4 Tuesday, 14 January 2020  Task 5  13586   Ibrahim Address 5 City 5
5 Tuesday, 14 January 2020  Task 6  13585   Kate Address 6 City 6
```

Here is my attempt.

```
def rowMerger(a,b):
    try:
        rule1 = lambda x: x not in ['']
        u = a.loc[a.iloc[:,0].apply(rule1) & a.iloc[:,1].apply(rule1) & a.iloc[:,2].apply(rule1)].index
        print(u)
        findMergerindexs = list(u)
        findMergerindexs.sort()
        a = pd.DataFrame(a)
        tabcolumns = pd.DataFrame(a.columns)
        totalcolumns = len(tabcolumns)
        b = pd.DataFrame(columns = list(tabcolumns))
        if (len(findMergerindexs) > 0):
            for m in range(len(findMergerindexs))
                if not (m == (len(findMergerindexs)-1)): 
                    startLoop = findMergerindexs[m]
                    endLoop = findMergerindexs[m+1]
                else:
                    startLoop = findMergerindexs[m]
                    endLoop = len(a)
                listValues = []
                for i in range(totalcolumns):
                    value = ' '
                    for n in range(startLoop,endLoop):
                        value = value + ' ' + str(a.iloc[n,i])
                    listValues.insert(i,(value.strip()))
                b = b.append(pd.Series(listValues),ignore_index = True)
        else:
            print("File is not having a row for merging instances - Please check the file manually for instance - ")
        return b
    except: 
        print("Error - While merging the rows")
    return b
```

And this code is giving me the output below.

```
rowMerger(df,0)
       0       1             2
0   Task 1  13588   Jack Address 1 City 1
1   Task 2  13589   Ammie Address 2 City
2   Task 3 Tuesday, 14 January 2020 13589   Amanda Address 3 City 3
3   Task 4  13587   Chelsea Address 4 City 4
4   Task 5  13586   Ibrahim Address 5 City 5
5   Task 6  13585   Kate Address 6 City 6
```

But the problem is that this code will only merge the rows. Not sure how to duplicate the dates across the respective rows as shown in the desired output and put it in a different column. Can anyone please help me on how to achieve this?

Comment: How is rowMerger(a,b) used in the example in your first code block. What is b?

Comment: b is a data frame that the function is returning. The function takes two parameters, data frame and 0. rowMerger(df,0) will give us the result I was showing above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
task_mask = df.Task.str.match("Task\s+\d")
df.assign(Task = df.Task[task_mask],
          Date = pd.Series(np.where(~task_mask, df["Task"], np.NaN)).shift()) \
        .replace("", np.NaN) \
        .dropna(how='all') \
        .ffill() \
        .groupby(["Task", "ID", "Date"]).agg({"Supervisor": lambda x: " ".join(x)}) \
        .reset_index()
```

*output*

```
#      Task     ID                      Date                Supervisor
# 0  Task 1  13588   Monday, 13 January 2020     Jack Address 1 City 1
# 1  Task 2  13589   Monday, 13 January 2020      Ammie Address 2 City
# 2  Task 3  13589   Monday, 13 January 2020   Amanda Address 3 City 3
# 3  Task 4  13587  Tuesday, 14 January 2020  Chelsea Address 4 City 4
# 4  Task 5  13586  Tuesday, 14 January 2020  Ibrahim Address 5 City 5
# 5  Task 6  13585  Tuesday, 14 January 2020     Kate Address 6 City 6
```

---

**Explanations**:

1. Filter the `Task` columns: `dates` and `task id`.

   - One solution is to use a regex to match `task id`. [`pandas.Series.str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) does the work. The regex used is quite simple: `"Task\s+\d"` means `Task` + any space + number.

```
task_mask = df.Task.str.match("Task\s+\d")
```

2. From this mask, we can extract the `Date` and the `Tasks`. The tasks are easily reachable from the `task_mask` with `df.Task[task_mask]`
3. The `Dates` are a tiny bit much more difficult to extract.

   - We use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to either set `Task` value or `NaN`.
   - Then, we convert this `array` into a [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html)
   - Finally, we shift all value by 1 using [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html). Shifting rows let us to easily remove the `NaN` rows in step 5.

```
pd.Series(np.where(~task_mask, df["Task"], np.NaN)).shift()
```

4. Replace all empty string to `NaN` using [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)
5. Remove empty rows (e.g. old rows where there is only `Date`) using [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with `how="all"`
6. Fill all `NaN` values with previous not `NaN` value using [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)
7. Groupby by `"Task", "ID"a and "Date"` and aggregate rows using [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html). The aggregation function is based on [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join): `lambda x: " ".join(x)`
8. Reset index from *groupby* using [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

Hope this is clear !

---

**Code + illustration**

```
# Create dataframe
data = [['Monday, 13 January 2020', '', ''], ['Task 1', 13588, 'Jack'], ['', '', 'Address 1'], ['', '', 'City 1'], ['Task 2', 13589, 'Ammie'], ['', '', 'Address 2'], ['', '', 'City'], ['Task 3', 13589, 'Amanda'], ['', '', 'Address 3'], ['', '', 'City 3'], [
    'Tuesday, 14 January 2020', '', ''], ['Task 4', 13587, 'Chelsea'], ['', '', 'Address 4'], ['', '', 'City 4'], ['Task 5', '13586', 'Ibrahim'], ['', '', 'Address 5'], ['', '', 'City 5'], ['Task 6', 13585, 'Kate'], ['', '', 'Address 6'], ['', '', 'City 6']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['Task', 'ID', 'Supervisor']
print(df)

# Step 1
task_mask = df.Task.str.match("Task\s+\d")
print(task_mask)
# 0     False
# 1      True
# 2     False
# 3     False
# 4      True
# 5     False
# 6     False
# 7      True
# 8     False
# 9     False
# 10    False
# 11     True
# 12    False
# 13    False
# 14     True
# 15    False
# 16    False
# 17     True
# 18    False
# 19    False
# Name: Task, dtype: bool

# Step 2
print(df.Task[task_mask])
# 1     Task 1
# 4     Task 2
# 7     Task 3
# 11    Task 4
# 14    Task 5
# 17    Task 6
# Name: Task, dtype: object

# Step 3
print(pd.Series(np.where(~task_mask, df["Task"], np.NaN)).shift())
# 0                          NaN
# 1      Monday, 13 January 2020
# 2                          NaN
# 3
# 4
# 5                          NaN
# 6
# 7
# 8                          NaN
# 9
# 10
# 11    Tuesday, 14 January 2020
# 12                         NaN
# 13
# 14
# 15                         NaN
# 16
# 17
# 18                         NaN
# 19
# dtype: object

# Step 4
print(df.assign(Task=df.Task[task_mask],
                Date=pd.Series(np.where(~task_mask, df["Task"], np.NaN)).shift())
        .replace("", np.NaN))
#       Task     ID Supervisor                      Date
# 0      NaN    NaN        NaN                       NaN
# 1   Task 1  13588       Jack   Monday, 13 January 2020
# 2      NaN    NaN  Address 1                       NaN
# 3      NaN    NaN     City 1                       NaN
# 4   Task 2  13589      Ammie                       NaN
# 5      NaN    NaN  Address 2                       NaN
# 6      NaN    NaN       City                       NaN
# 7   Task 3  13589     Amanda                       NaN
# 8      NaN    NaN  Address 3                       NaN
# 9      NaN    NaN     City 3                       NaN
# 10     NaN    NaN        NaN                       NaN
# 11  Task 4  13587    Chelsea  Tuesday, 14 January 2020
# 12     NaN    NaN  Address 4                       NaN
# 13     NaN    NaN     City 4                       NaN
# 14  Task 5  13586    Ibrahim                       NaN
# 15     NaN    NaN  Address 5                       NaN
# 16     NaN    NaN     City 5                       NaN
# 17  Task 6  13585       Kate                       NaN
# 18     NaN    NaN  Address 6                       NaN
# 19     NaN    NaN     City 6                       NaN

# Step 5:
print(df.assign(Task = df.Task[task_mask],
                Date = pd.Series(np.where(~task_mask, df["Task"], np.NaN)).shift()) \
        .replace("", np.NaN) \
        .dropna(how='all'))
#       Task     ID Supervisor                      Date
# 1   Task 1  13588       Jack   Monday, 13 January 2020
# 2      NaN    NaN  Address 1                       NaN
# 3      NaN    NaN     City 1                       NaN
# 4   Task 2  13589      Ammie                       NaN
# 5      NaN    NaN  Address 2                       NaN
# 6      NaN    NaN       City                       NaN
# 7   Task 3  13589     Amanda                       NaN
# 8      NaN    NaN  Address 3                       NaN
# 9      NaN    NaN     City 3                       NaN
# 11  Task 4  13587    Chelsea  Tuesday, 14 January 2020
# 12     NaN    NaN  Address 4                       NaN
# 13     NaN    NaN     City 4                       NaN
# 14  Task 5  13586    Ibrahim                       NaN
# 15     NaN    NaN  Address 5                       NaN
# 16     NaN    NaN     City 5                       NaN
# 17  Task 6  13585       Kate                       NaN
# 18     NaN    NaN  Address 6                       NaN
# 19     NaN    NaN     City 6                       NaN

# Step 6:
print(df.assign(Task = df.Task[task_mask],
                 Date = pd.Series(np.where(~task_mask, df["Task"], np.NaN)).shift()) \
            .replace("", np.NaN) \
            .dropna(how='all') \
            .ffill())
#       Task     ID Supervisor                      Date
# 1   Task 1  13588       Jack   Monday, 13 January 2020
# 2   Task 1  13588  Address 1   Monday, 13 January 2020
# 3   Task 1  13588     City 1   Monday, 13 January 2020
# 4   Task 2  13589      Ammie   Monday, 13 January 2020
# 5   Task 2  13589  Address 2   Monday, 13 January 2020
# 6   Task 2  13589       City   Monday, 13 January 2020
# 7   Task 3  13589     Amanda   Monday, 13 January 2020
# 8   Task 3  13589  Address 3   Monday, 13 January 2020
# 9   Task 3  13589     City 3   Monday, 13 January 2020
# 11  Task 4  13587    Chelsea  Tuesday, 14 January 2020
# 12  Task 4  13587  Address 4  Tuesday, 14 January 2020
# 13  Task 4  13587     City 4  Tuesday, 14 January 2020
# 14  Task 5  13586    Ibrahim  Tuesday, 14 January 2020
# 15  Task 5  13586  Address 5  Tuesday, 14 January 2020
# 16  Task 5  13586     City 5  Tuesday, 14 January 2020
# 17  Task 6  13585       Kate  Tuesday, 14 January 2020
# 18  Task 6  13585  Address 6  Tuesday, 14 January 2020
# 19  Task 6  13585     City 6  Tuesday, 14 January 2020

# Step 7
print(df.assign(Task = df.Task[task_mask],
                Date = pd.Series(np.where(~task_mask, df["Task"], np.NaN)).shift()) \
        .replace("", np.NaN) \
        .dropna(how='all') \
        .ffill() \
        .groupby(["Task", "ID", "Date"]).agg({"Supervisor": lambda x: " ".join(x)}))
#                                                      Supervisor
# Task   ID    Date
# Task 1 13588 Monday, 13 January 2020      Jack Address 1 City 1
# Task 2 13589 Monday, 13 January 2020       Ammie Address 2 City
# Task 3 13589 Monday, 13 January 2020    Amanda Address 3 City 3
# Task 4 13587 Tuesday, 14 January 2020  Chelsea Address 4 City 4
# Task 5 13586 Tuesday, 14 January 2020  Ibrahim Address 5 City 5
# Task 6 13585 Tuesday, 14 January 2020     Kate Address 6 City 6

# Step 8
df = df.assign(Task = df.Task[task_mask],
               Date = pd.Series(np.where(~task_mask, df["Task"], np.NaN)).shift()) \
        .replace("", np.NaN) \
        .dropna(how='all') \
        .ffill() \
        .groupby(["Task", "ID", "Date"]).agg({"Supervisor": lambda x: " ".join(x)}) \
        .reset_index()
print(df)

#      Task     ID                      Date                Supervisor
# 0  Task 1  13588   Monday, 13 January 2020     Jack Address 1 City 1
# 1  Task 2  13589   Monday, 13 January 2020      Ammie Address 2 City
# 2  Task 3  13589   Monday, 13 January 2020   Amanda Address 3 City 3
# 3  Task 4  13587  Tuesday, 14 January 2020  Chelsea Address 4 City 4
# 4  Task 5  13586  Tuesday, 14 January 2020  Ibrahim Address 5 City 5
# 5  Task 6  13585  Tuesday, 14 January 2020     Kate Address 6 City 6
```

Answer (score 2):

@Alexandre's answer is great - this is an alternative, where I avoid the regex extraction and shift, :

```
#convert empty cells to null
(df.replace("",np.nan)
 #create a new column containing only the dates
 #we'll use the null cells in Supervisor column to pick out the dates
 .assign(Date = lambda x: x.loc[x.Supervisor.isna(),'Task'])
 .ffill()
 .dropna(subset=['ID'])
 #drop Dates found in the Task column
 .query('Task != Date')
 .groupby(['Date','Task','ID'],as_index=False)
 .Supervisor.agg(' '.join)
)

        Date                    Task      ID      Supervisor
0   Monday, 13 January 2020     Task 1  13588   Jack Address 1 City 1
1   Monday, 13 January 2020     Task 2  13589   Ammie Address 2 City
2   Monday, 13 January 2020     Task 3  13589   Amanda Address 3 City 3
3   Tuesday, 14 January 2020    Task 4  13587   Chelsea Address 4 City 4
4   Tuesday, 14 January 2020    Task 5  13586   Ibrahim Address 5 City 5
5   Tuesday, 14 January 2020    Task 6  13585   Kate Address 6 City 6
```

Answer (score 1):

So essentially we use lambda to separate the Date from the task number and `pd.Series.fillna(method='ffill')` to fill in the last valid date.

So we're going to add these lines:

```
# Split Date column
df['Date'] = df.apply(lambda x: " ".join(x[0].split(' ')[2:]) if len(x[0].split(' ')) > 2 else np.nan,axis=1).fillna(method='ffill')

# Clean Task column
df['Task'] = df.apply(lambda x: " ".join(x[0].split(' ')[:2]) if len(x[0].split(' ')) > 1 else x[0],axis=1)

# Rename and reorder remaining columns
df['ID'] = df[1]
df['Supervisor'] = df[2]
df = df[['Date','Task','ID','Supervisor']]
```